# C# How to upload file by http?

Tags: c#, upload

Im looking for solution how can I upload some file using http request. I got the idea that I'll transfer my files by post and on PHP side I'll put files on the server.

How doin this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
client.UploadFile(address, filename);
```

See [UploadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36s52zhs.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks, but how's called post field?

Answer (score 0):

Well I'd try the simplest possible thing that might work to start with - [`WebClient.UploadFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploadfile.aspx):

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.UploadFile(url, file);
```

Of course, you'll have to write appropriate PHP code to handle the upload...

Answer (score 0):

One more approach is to upload file via browser and handle upload request/response with Fiddler. After that, you can write exact request using HttpWebRequest via C#.